# Why am I getting this read error and the echo function is echoing the image name?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Grab the profile data from the POST
  $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['firstname']));
  $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['lastname']));
  $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['gender']));
  $birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['birthdate']));
  $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['city']));
  $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['state']));
  $old_picture = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['old_picture']));
  $new_picture = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_FILES['new_picture']['tmp_name']));
  echo $new_picture;
  $new_picture_type = $_FILES['new_picture']['type'];
  $new_picture_size = $_FILES['new_picture']['size'];
  The line below is where the problem is.
  list($new_picture_width, $new_picture_height) = getimagesize($new_picture);
```

This is what the code is echoing:

```
/tmp/phpSdyj9D 
Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /var/www/html/ch07.5/initial/mismatch/editprofile.php on line 54
```

I've tried everything. I edited my `php.ini` file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 250M
post_max_size = 250M
max_execution_time = 300

date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

This still didn't work. I changed the code only to get different errors like:

```
Fail to open stream.
```

With all this confusion the picture still won't upload.

I hope I can get some help with this seeing that all the other answers on the internet didn't help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure `/tmp/phpSdyj9D` exists

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: SSH to server and issue  command `ls -la /tmp/phpSdyj9D`

Comment: I issued the command in the server but it gave me an error. I think I did the wrong thing tho, I'm sorta new to this. What exactly should I do?

Comment: check your folder has write permission, Also check your log to get the exact error.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. << This is the permissions on my images folder. The image is not in the images folder either. The error logs is saying: File name cannot be empty and a Read error.

Comment: print $_FILES to check where there is 'name'

Comment: remove mysqli_real_escape_string                                                $new_picture = $_FILES['new_picture']['tmp_name'];

Comment: I removed that line of code and it still didn't work.